# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error in some android devices

Tags: android

I am developing an android game and it is working properly in my galaxy j5 prime but when it tested it in other devices then in some of them the application stops on its own showing the error given below.

Information about the game: it has several layout in it, inside a frame layout and i am using setvisiblity to hide and show the layouts and one of the layout has the surfaceview added dynamically to it. It also has Media Player object in it for game sound.
App stops when the layout having surface view inside in it is visible.

I am not getting what kind of error this is and why this error is generating in some devices.

Logcat :

```
12-21 10:34:11.058 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
12-21 10:34:11.058 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
12-21 10:34:11.068 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-21 10:34:11.068 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
12-21 10:34:11.068 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
12-21 10:34:11.078 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-21 10:34:11.078 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:11.078 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:11.088 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:11.098 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:11.098 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:11.098 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:12.008 9332-9344/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
 12-21 10:34:12.008 9332-9344/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
 12-21 10:34:12.008 9332-9344/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
 12-21 10:34:23.838 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:23.848 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:23.858 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:23.858 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:23.858 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:23.878 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:23.878 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:23.878 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 12-21 10:34:23.888 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:23.928 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:23.928 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:23.928 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 12-21 10:34:24.418 9332-9344/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
 12-21 10:34:24.418 9332-9344/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
 12-21 10:34:24.418 9332-9344/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
 12-21 10:34:31.398 9332-9347/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46738(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 14MB/18MB, paused 951us total 101.562ms
 12-21 10:34:50.498 9332-9332/com.example.prashant.dodgeballfinal A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 9332 (.dodgeballfinal)

                                                                     [ 12-21 10:34:50.498   321:  321 W/         ]
                                                                     handle_request(11) debug_value = false;


                                                                     [ 12-21 10:34:50.498   321:  321 W/         ]
                                                                     wait_for_sigstope = 19

                                                                     [ 12-21 10:34:50.548   321:  321 W/         ]
                                                                     wait_for_sigstope = 11
```

Comment: did you use largeheap for your application?

Comment: Yeah i tried that but i not worked for me. I also tried to use hardware accelerated on but it not worked.

Comment: what's your file size?

Comment: Are you talking about the media file size? i have 4 media files one of them is of 2mb others are small like 4-5kb

Comment: I think the second last error in the logcat is the main cause due to which application stops. I think it is something related to garbage collection, i m not sure but i think gc removed some objects due to which i m getting fatal signal 11 which is segmentation fault and because of this app stops. may be